# Creating a QML type whose properties are read-only except for initialization?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick, qproperty

I want to implement a QML type in C++.  Said QML type is supposed to be loaded from a `Component` or similar, like so:

```
Component {
  id: jesseMaker

  JesseType {
    id: doge
    something: "wow"
    oops: 67
    yes: "hurray"
  }
}
```

Notice how there's nothing unusual about this initialization.  **However**, I also want the following JavaScript to be **invalid** at the denoted points:

```
function somewhereElse() {
  var thing = jesseMaker.createObject(this, {"something": "yay"}); // OK
  thing.oops = 12; // Should be an ERROR, as if this Q_PROPERTY had no WRITE
}
```

**To achieve my stated goals, how can I define the relevant properties?**

Comment: have you tried setting `oops` property to `readonly` in the `JesseType` component? subclasses can still overrite `readonly` properties but not outsiders. Just a thought!

Comment: I guess that isn't possible. There is no difference in property visibility if that static or dynamic creation. So if a property is readonly (what you expect for) you cannot set it in the initialization time too.